# Can't change all pixel of an image to selected color

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem with this code, I don't know why it only replace first 60 pixel of my image (j from 0 to 59), all the other is not (j in loop from 60 to 360). I just tested, it still come to other case, but it didn't replace these pixel with my selected color:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 360; j++)
        {
            if (j > 300)
            {
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 0;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 255;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = 0;
            }
            else if (j > 240)
            {
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 0;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 0;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = 255;
            }
            else if (j > 180)
            {
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 0;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 255;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = 0;
            }
            else if (j > 120)
            {
                putText(color_bar, "120", Point2f(2, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, Scalar(0, 0, 255, 255));
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 255;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 0;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = 0;
            }
            else if (j > 60)
            {
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 0;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 255;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[2] = 0;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[1] = 0;
                color_bar.at<Vec3b>(i, j)[0] = 255;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my result image:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n27h9.png)

Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After opening your image, i see picture with cols == 40 and rows == 360, so you should access elements using

```
color_bar.at<Vec3b>(j,i)[..] = value;
```

j - is row, i - is col.